# Prevent UDP forwarding

Tags: networking, udp, iptables, forwarding, ddos

I've noticed my server is being used to relay UDP traffic as part of a DDOS.

Various source IPs send UDP datagrams with TARGET_IP set as the destination. My server's IP is *not* TARGET_IP so I'm just forwarding the attack.

So far, I'm DROPing all UDP traffic to the TARGET_IP thanks to *iptables* but I wonder if this is a normal behavior, i.e. that someone can send UDP traffic to TARGET_IP *through* my server, using it as a proxy.

Is there any way to prevent that at the kernel level (before it goes through *iptables*)?

EDIT: I can't disable IP forwarding.

Comment: Please show the output of the following command (as root): `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route`

Comment: @MikePennington: `net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't intend your server to route traffic, [disable IP forwarding](http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/). Then your machine will only be be able to send and receive packets destined to / originating from itself. That's usually the default setting for Linux distros.

To check if IP forwarding is enabled, use `sysctl` or check under `/proc` (1 = enabled, 0 = disabled):

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0

# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
0
```

To disable IP forwarding, use either of these commands:

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0

# echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

That will disable it on-the-fly. The change will be lost if you reboot. To make a permanent change, edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

For more details, see the article [How to Enable IP Forwarding in Linux](http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't disable IP forwarding since the server needs to forward traffic from/to several VMs so this is not an option for me. My question is then is there any better way than `iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 ! -d VMs_SUBNET -j DROP`?